# Call select name in another button using javascript in symfony...omù

Tags: javascript, select, alert

i'm using javascript with symfony 1.4

```
$("#annonc").change( function() {

    var _annonce = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        ...........

}

$("#btn_valider").click( function(){
         alert();
}
```

How can i do an alert to show selected option in my bloc   $("#btn_valider") ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#btn_valider").click( function(){
     alert($("#annonc").val());
}
```

or alternatively

```
$("#btn_valider").click( function(){
     alert($("#annonc option:selected").attr('value'));
}
```

Comment: the seceond one is operational :

$("#btn_valider").click( function(){
     alert($("#annonc option:selected").attr('value'));
}

Comment: You're right, the first one had a wrong function name (it should be `.val()` and not `.value()`) - corrected now, so both cases should be working now